# Django redirect after login loses query string

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view that requires a user to login. It can optionally receive some querystring parameters.
The problem is that the querystring is lost after the user successful login.

My view:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@login_required
@permission_required('MyApp.view_usage',raise_exception=True)
def pdfParser(request):
    return render(request,'MyApp/dashboard.html',{})
```

The url I am calling to get to that view (with the login redirect):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/OldStyle/%3FDOCUMENT_ID%3Dlkpto%26SERIES%3D0001
```

Url that is generated after the login:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/OldStyle
```

Where/What should I do to intercept and fix it?

EDIT:
What I want is to find out if I need to rewrite the login view, since I am using the delivered django auth login view OR there is a setup(settings) to make the querystring goes automatically to the redirected view

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you wanna do, but if you need some sort of storage, you can use django session framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: @AndreiOsmolovskii I need a way to intercept the login flow so I can store the values OR make sure django will redirect me back to the correct url after the login

Comment: You can store data within views like so: `request.session['key'] = some_params` and you can request it in other views `params = request.session.get['key']`. To redirect users  there is a function: `from django.shortcuts import redirect`. So it looks pretty straightforward to me, but maybe I'm still missing the problem.

Comment: @AndreiOsmolovskii I know how to use sessions.... is the redirect part that I dont get... I am using delivered auth login, so I dont have control over the login view... .let me edit the question so I made myself more clear of what I expect

Comment: Do you mean built-in LoginView or some 3rd party auth lib? Sure you can put a lot of your own logic inside LoginView by overriding default attributes like `successful_url` (to specify where user should be redirected after successful login) or some methods like `dispatch()` (to execute some logic in prior to everything else). https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.views/LoginView/

Comment: I want to keep it simple, is there a way to force django to redirect keeping the querystring?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209112/discussion-between-andrei-osmolovskii-and-walucas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was on my own html.... I had to add the `?next={{next|urlencode}}` on the action to make it work.....

so now my login.html form looks like this:

```
 <form class="user" method='POST' action="{% url 'login' %}?next={{next|urlencode}}">
```

Comment: Thanks @Walucas. I struggled for an hour. Almost modified the POST request to fetch query params from the META.referrer.